# Locked to version problem when upgrading

Tags: composer, 9, upgrading

Every time I run the composer command to upgrade Drupal 8.9.16 to Drupal 9, it notifies me that there is a problem with a module.

For example, I run:

```
composer require drupal/core --with-all-dependencies
```

I get:

```
Using version ^9.2 for drupal/core
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update drupal/core --with-all-dependencies
Gathering patches from patch file.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - drupal/twig_tweak is locked to version 2.9.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - drupal/twig_tweak 2.9.0 requires drupal/core ^8.7 || ^9.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[9.2.0-alpha1, ..., 9.3.x-dev].
    - drupal/core[9.2.0-alpha1, ..., 9.3.x-dev] require symfony/routing ^4.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/routing[v4.4.0-BETA1, ..., 4.4.x-dev].
    - symfony/routing v4.4.25 conflicts with symfony/routing v4.4.25.
    - symfony/routing v4.4.24 conflicts with symfony/routing v4.4.24.
    - symfony/routing v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/routing v4.4.22.
.....
.....
```

In this case, twig_tweak is already at 2.9.0, which supports Drupal 9, but it is complaining about it. I have been removing the problem module from composer.json and then running `composer update`, but every time I run `composer require drupal/core --with-all-dependencies` another module shows up with the same issue. I feel like I may be doing something wrong.

Comment: Are you using `core-recommended` as described in the docs? https://www.drupal.org/docs/updating-drupal/updating-drupal-core-via-composer

Comment: My composer.json doesn't currently use `core-recommended`.

Comment: You need to update all the contributed modules before attempting the core upgrade - see https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/how-to-prepare-your-drupal-7-or-8-site-for-drupal-9/upgrading-a-drupal-8-site. [Upgrade status](https://www.drupal.org/project/upgrade_status) is very useful to get a list of what needs updating and what's available

Comment: Hi @Clive, I did run Upgrade Status and everything should be updated but I'm still getting these errors. For example, in this case, twig-tweak is at 2.9.0 which should support Drupal 9.

Comment: Did you use composer to update the modules? If not then composer won’t know you’ve done it

Comment: @Clive I did update all with composer.

Comment: Assuming your project is checked in to version control, try deleting `composer.lock` and `/vendor` and then running `composer update`.  This is the nuclear option but I've used it on several sites to update to D9.

Answer (score -1):

Once you need to update the current code follow the below steps:

Step 1: Run command:

**composer update**

Step 2: You need to update the current code with an update to Drupal 8 and update using custom theme and module version

**core_version_requirement: ^8.9 || ^9**

SO current code and modules are ready to be upgraded with Drupal 9. This way we can reduce errors.

Step 3: Create a default folder and set the file to be editable.

chmod 777 web/sites/default
find web/sites/default -name "*settings.php" -exec chmod 777 {} ;
find web/sites/default -name "*services.yml" -exec chmod 777 {} ;

Step 4: Run These Commands (This Command Edits Your Composer File to Be Upgrade Ready)

**composer require drupal/core-recommended:^9 drupal/core-composer-scaffold:^9 drupal/core-project-message:^9 --update-with-dependencies --no-update**

If you have drupal/core-dev installed.

**composer require drupal/core-dev:^9 --dev --update-with-dependencies --no-update**

Step 5: Run command

**composer require "drupal/core:9.2.1 as 8.9.16" --no-update && composer update**

Step 6: Run **Drush updatedb command**

If you face any problem with core then

Step 6.1: Run **Composer outdated "drupal/*"** and update this listed module into the Drupal 9 version and upgrade the appropriate custom modules and themes with Drupal 9.

Step 6.2: **$config_directories['sync']** change to **$settings["config_sync_directory"]**

https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-to-drupal-9-or-later